# Type constraints with type stored in a variable

Tags: c#

I'm trying to write a function that takes a parameter of a type that can be defined in a child class.

example:

```
public abstract class Base
{
    public abstract Type ComponentTypeNeeded { get; }
    public abstract void Do(ComponentTypeNeeded component);
}
```

what I tried:

```
public abstract class Base
{
    public abstract Type ComponentTypeNeeded { get; }
    public abstract void Do<T>(T component) where T : ComponentTypeNeeded;
}
```

That obviously didn't work, which sense to me but I couldn't think of any other solution.

I hope someone here can help me, so thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to make your entire class generic.

Comment: ^ Imo post as answer so it can be accepted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public abstract class Base<T>
{
    public abstract void Do(T component);
}
```

That should give you everything you need. Just create an sub class like this example

```
public class SubClass: Base<string>
{
    public override void Do(string component)
    {
        //implementation
    }
}
```